# Receiving 403 Forbidden Error when uploading certain bz2 files as Block Blob through Azure Portal

Tags: azure, blob, http-status-code-403, portal, bz2

I am using Azure Portal to upload a bunch of bz2 files manually as block blobs with 4MB block size to a single container.  I am the owner of the container.  I am able to upload bz2 files as block blobs that range from 2 MB to 75MB.  However, there are two bz2 files, one that is 28 MB and the other which is 50MB that I receive the 403 forbidden error. The files were all created using 7-zip at roughly the same time. Why am I getting 403 error for 2 files and not for the other 7?  I am the subscription owner.

I recreated the bz2 files on my local, and tried again with the same result. I was however able to upload those two files as append blobs.

When I zip these two files using gzip instead of bz2, I do not receive the 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in environment I got the same error as below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, check whether you are using authentication type as account key and select block size as 75mb for those two files

when I run the same bz2 files in block blob and type as account key it uploaded successfully like below:

[image]

Try to give access to storage blob data contributor role and reader role assignment and check whether you have allowed networking and firewall is enabled from all networks like below:

***Go to storage account: under “security+ networking” ->  Networking -> Select Enabled from all networks-> save.***

[image]

Comment: This could be dangerous as anybody can upload file to it if the person has some rights.